# How to use MAX and COUNT function simultaneously on two different tables which are applied with a JOIN?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
//Pig Program

User = LOAD 'path' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, reputation:int, displayname:chararray, loc:chararray, age:int);

Post = LOAD 'path' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, post_type:int, creationdate:chararray, score:int, viewcount:int, ownerus)er_id:int, title:chararray, answercount:chararray, commentcount:chararray);

JOIN User BY id, Post BY id;

a = JOIN User BY id, Post BY id;

DUMP a;

User_Group = Group a ALL;

Max_reputation = foreach User_Group Generate(User.displayname, User.reputation, Post.id), MAX(User.reputation), COUNT(Post.id);
```

So basically i grouped two different tables i.e. User and Post
Then applied a JOIN to it.

Problem statment :To find displayname and no of posts of user having Maximum reputation.

So basically i need displayname and reputation from User

And also id from Post

And i want to apply MAX(User.reputation) and Count(Post.id) on the JOIN i.e. a

Please Help.

What is more useful , applying JOIN and then doing MAX and Count or
Applying MAX and Count and then doing JOIN.

Comment: I want to apply count on one file and max on other file. Then i need to join. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem statement :To find displayname and no of posts of user having Maximum reputation.

At first try to find the displayname of user who is having maximum reputation  with the help of relation "user"

and then apply join with relation "post" to gather all post's by that max user.. then apply a grouping on basis on id and take the count .

The below code will help you to reach your goal

```
User = LOAD 'path' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, reputation:int, displayname:chararray, loc:chararray, age:int);

Post = LOAD 'path' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, post_type:int, creationdate:chararray,score:int, viewcount:int, ownerus)er_id:int, title:chararray, answercount:chararray);

User_grp = GROUP User BY id;

User_each = FOREACH User_grp 
                 {
                   User_order = ORDER User BY reputation DESC;
                   User_limit = LIMIT User_order 1;
                   User_nested = FOREACH User_limit GENERATE id,displayname;
                   GENERATE flatten(user_nested) as  (user_id,displayname);
                 };
User_join = JOIN User_each by user_id, Post by id; 

User_grouping = GROUP User_join BY user_id;

User_output  = FOREACH User_grouping GENERATE group as user_id, MAX(user_join.displayname) as displayname, COUNT(user_join.post_type) as post_cnts;
```

Comment: Thank you. i"ll try and let you know.